# How to retrieve the current server side datetime in Google App Engine with Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

So this is my code to generate the current datetime for make an insertion in the google table jiql_registrations

```
    Date fecha = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {
        Conn = ConexionGoogle.obtenerConexion();
        Statement Stmt = Conn.createStatement();



        Stmt.execute("insert or replace INTO registrations VALUES('" + user + "','"
                + identity + "','" + dateFormat.format(fecha) + "')");

        if (Conn != null)
            Conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        return "\t<update>false</update>";
    }
    return "\t<update>true</update>";
```

But when i look in the google dataviewer in the app dashboard i see the correct date but the time is set to 00:00:00

So if anyone can help me i will appreciate too much...

Comment: GAE lets you execute SQL statements? Are you sure this is Google *App Engine*?

Comment: well i think that statement works i got it from an adobe example

Comment: and you're executing this code on Google's App Engine platform? You're deploying the app to http://code.google.com/appengine/ ?

Comment: thats right man...the problem in the time reflects when i query the rows in the dataviewer in the gae dashboard, the time looks like  2010-10-15 00:00:00 i dont know what is happenin with the hour minutes & seconds..

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that you are building the SQL dynamically with string concatenation (SQL injection), you should try outputting the date in the logs. AFAIK, App Engine uses the default Java logging facility. This might need some configuration but if you are developing with Eclipse and the Google plug-in, there should be an example included.
Maybe the date column in the registration table just doesn't support time?

Comment: Thanks a lot man... I need that field to query on the logged users

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using the [java.sql.Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) object to store fetcha.

If you look at the API for this, the Date object only stores year/month/day

> SQL Date values do not have a time
>   component

Comment: well im using java.util.Date and when i exxecute the same operation in my local Mysql server it has no problems...